# Cloud Function to Authenticate a User

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am attempting to authenticate a user to access various scopes in the user Gsuite. I can run the code locally but I cannot seem to get it accepted as a cloud function.

I have tried deploying with firebase and with gcloud. I have checked my eslint settings.

This code is coming from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/README.md#oauth2-client

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const opn = require('open');
const destroyer = require('server-destroy');

const {google} = require('googleapis');

/**
 * To use OAuth2 authentication, we need access to a a CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, AND REDIRECT_URI.  To get these credentials for your application, visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.
 */
const keyPath = path.join(__dirname, 'credentials.json');
let keys = {redirect_uris: ['']};
if (fs.existsSync(keyPath)) {
  keys = require(keyPath).web;
}

/**
 * Create a new OAuth2 client with the configured keys.
 */
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  keys.client_id,
  keys.client_secret,
  `http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback`
);

/**
 * This is one of the many ways you can configure googleapis to use authentication credentials.  In this method, we're setting a global reference for all APIs.  Any other API you use here, like google.drive('v3'), will now use this auth client. You can also override the auth client at the service and method call levels.
 */
google.options({auth: oauth2Client});
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents'];
/**
 * Open an http server to accept the oauth callback. In this simple example, the only request to our webserver is to /callback?code=<code>
 */
async function authenticate(){
    // grab the url that will be used for authorization
    const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: scopes
    });

    const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
          if (req.url.indexOf('/oauth2callback') > -1) {
            const qs = new url.URL(req.url, 'http://localhost:3000').searchParams;
            res.end('Authentication successful! Please return to the console.');
            server.destroy();
            const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
            oauth2Client.credentials = tokens; // eslint-disable-line require-atomic-updates
            resolve(oauth2Client);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      })

      .listen(3000, () => {
        // open the browser to the authorize url to start the workflow
        opn(authorizeUrl, {wait: false}).then(cp => cp.unref())
        .catch(
            error => { 
            console.log(error);
        });
      });

    destroyer(server)
     .then(client => runSample(client)).catch(
         error => { 
         console.log(error);
       });
};
module.exports.authenticate=authenticate;

async function runSample(client) {
  // retrieve user profile
  console.log(client);
  const docs = google.docs({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: client
  });
  const createResponse = await docs.documents.create({
    requestBody: {
      title: 'Your new document!',
    },
  });
}
```

I expect it to load as a cloud function to firebase or gcloud. 
However:
Firebase returns "Deploy complete" but it never shows in the functions. 
gcloud returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token function" with the word function indicated in "async function authenticate(){"

I'm new to node.js and may be missing something really obvious to others.

Comment: You will never get User Credentials (Client ID/Client Secret) to work in Cloud Functions (meaning authenticate and create credentials). OAuth requires a web browser and a human. Neither one exists in Cloud Functions. Use a Service Account instead.

Comment: I was expecting to engage the oAuth process with a cloud function through an http trigger, redirect for approval and return with the token code to make calls to APIs. My understanding with service accounts is a limitation of the scopes they can access. Am I mistaken?

Comment: If you are concerned about scopes, put them in your question. In order to use Cloud Functions to specify the `redirect_uri` you need to know/manage the domain name. You cannot with Cloud Functions. Cloud Run or App Engine is a better choice.

Comment: I’m concerned with knowing by how this could and should work. I’m use to Apps Script. This is my first attempt with Node.js and I’d like to be pointed to any resources that could help. I’m specifically aiming to link with dialogflow.

Comment: The first step is to understand how OAuth works. Here is an article that I wrote that uses curl: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/

Comment: Once you have figured out OAuth, then you need to understand the HTTP header `Authorization: bearer token`. After that you will know how to authorize requests to any Google service.

Comment: @John Hanley  could you post your first comment as the answer, it seems like the proper answer for the question in place.

Answer (score 1):

> You will never get User Credentials (Client ID/Client Secret) to work
>   in Cloud Functions (meaning authenticate and create credentials).
>   OAuth requires a web browser and a human. Neither one exists in Cloud
>   Functions. Use a Service Account instead. – John Hanley